# add chrome to path in mac but failed to start chrome in terminal by typing `Google\ Chrome`

Tags: google-chrome, mac, zsh

## environments

❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.6
BuildVersion:   19G2021

❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)

## problem description

i added the dir `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/` of chrome path `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome` to my PATH, which finally looks like:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/:/Users/xiaojguan/Library/Python/3.7/bin/:/Users/xiaojguan/Library/Python/3.7/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but i failed to type `Google\ Chrome` to start chrome but it is ok to start chrome with `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

thanks in advance

Comment: What does `which "Google Chrome"` print?

Comment: What does `print -l $path` show?

Comment: ❯ which "Google Chrome"
Google Chrome not found

Comment: ❯ print -l $path
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/
/Users/xiaojguan/Library/Python/3.7/bin/
/Users/xiaojguan/Library/Python/3.7/bin/
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin